# Using JavaScript prompt to get input and pass it along

Tags: javascript, html

Well.. I am having a brain fart. Maybe I have worked to long today and need to step away. Anyways, what I am trying to do is get binary input, use javascript to shoot up a prompt where the user will enter keys needed. Their answer will then be passed into a input.

```
    <!Doctype html>
<html>
<h1> Java input on Option change </h1>

<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>option</td>
        <td>
<select id="keyselect" onchange="keyPrompt()" >
    <option value="0">No</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input name="keys" id="keysneeded" hidden>
<p id="keysneeded"> </p>
</body>
<script>
function keyPrompt()
{
    var k = document.getElementByID("keyselect").value;
        if (k != 1);{
            var keys = prompt("What keys are needed?");
            document.getElementByID("keysneeded").innerHTML = keys;
        }

    }


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`

Comment: ... and `getElementById` instead of `getElementByID`.

Comment: @Rayon  Thanks for the fresh eyes maybe i should just go to bed for the night :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @teemu said in comments `getElementById` instead of `getElementByID` and use different ids for each control. And also remove the `;` after if condition.

```js
function keyPrompt() {
  var k = document.getElementById("keyselect").value;
  if (k != 1) {
    var keys = prompt("What keys are needed?");
    document.getElementById("keysneeded").innerText = keys;
    document.getElementById("hidInput").value = keys;
  }

}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<h1> Java input on Option change </h1>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>option</td>
      <td>
        <select id="keyselect" onchange="keyPrompt()">
          <option value="0">No</option>
          <option value="1">Yes</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <input name="keys" id="hidInput" hidden>
  <p id="keysneeded"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Sanker Thanks. Will mark as answered as soon as it lets me. I dont know how i didnt catch my simple mistakes. one of those nights

Comment: ha ha. it happens. good night.